# What name does VisualVM use for threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, jvisualvm

I have an application with a lot of threads. I'm trying to analyze a specific thread's call stack in VisualVM.

I'm logging the thread name in my application like so:

```
log.warn("Placard thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
```

But the threads in VisualVM are all named like Thread-47, Thread-48, Timer-2, and so on. Where are the thread names in VisualVM coming from? How can I connect them with some value that I can use programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe threads have both a name and id, so it could be `thread.getName() + '-' + thread.getId()`.

Comment: You can name your threads, it makes it easier to know what's going on.
Thread.currentThread().setName("My Thread that does interesting things")